# AWS Api gateway custom domain replaces host header

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway

I have a Route 53 with my public domain pointing to an AWS API Gateway w/ a Custom domain and finally redirecting to an Nginx running under EC2. Something like that:

```
ROUTE 53 --> AWS API Gateway w/ Custom Domain --> NGINX
```

In Nginx, I have 3 servers blocks:

- subdomain1.mydomain go to `/sub1` folder
- subdomain2.mydomain go to `/sub2` folder
- mydomain go to `/` (root) folder

Since Nginx relies on `host header` it expects to receive the host according to the domain. But according to the [AWS docs](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/forward-host-header-api-gateway), the AWS API Gateway replaces the host header received from Route 53 to the integration endpoint dns, what's causing problems for me, since nginx doesn't know what do to with that odd dns.